# There are two versions of RichTextBox in msdn. Why do exist two versions?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, msdn

There are two versions of RichTextBox in msdn (.NET Framework 4.5.).  Why do exist two versions? They all have different properties. For example look at

```
AcceptsReturn.
```

I don't know what is the correct version.

[RichTextBox msdn1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)

[RichTextBox msdn2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612650.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

- [`System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) is for Windows Forms applications
- [`System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612650.aspx) is for WPF applications (and Silverlight)

They're two separate GUI frameworks with different sets of controls.

> I don't know what is the correct version.

Well are you building a Windows Forms application or a WPF application?

Comment: How do you know that System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox intended for WPF? Is "Controls" mean intended for WPF? I'm building for windows forms.

Comment: @Voloda2: Basically System.Windows.* other than System.Windows.Forms is for WPF.

Comment: (Added Silverlight into the mix as well, which is similar to WPF.)

Comment: The docs provide two conclusive indicators that `S.W.C.RTB` is for WPF: "Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)", and seeing `System.Windows.UIElement` in the inheritance tree.